# DialogFlow Suggestion Chips - Web Browser not serving Suggestions

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I've been Working with DialogFlow for about a week, so excuse my ignorance if I've overlooked something.

I have Intents and Contexts chaining and working very well so far. Though Suggestion Chips as of yet dont appear except in the simulator. Not in the Integrations demo of Web. I'm using actions in with fulfillment to add a suggestion though its just showing the first message and no Suggestions.

```
 function gender(agent) {

    agent.add("Are you Male or Female?");
    agent.add(new Suggestion(`Male`));
    agent.add(new Suggestion(`Female`));
    agent.add(new Suggestion(`Other`));
    agent.setContext({ name: 'get_gender', lifespan: 2});
  }
```

Any suggestions / help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kieran

Comment: Can you update your question to show a little bit more of the code? Is this the Intent Handler, and how are you registering it? Which library are you using? Can you include screen shots that illustrate it when it is working and when it isn't?

Comment: It's also worth noting that the Suggestion constructor will take an array of strings, so your code could be simplified to `new Suggestion(['Male','Female','Other'])` . but then that does assume youre using the correct device type, as you need to check that the device supports it by querying `conv.surface.capabilities.has('actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT') `as if you send suggestions to an audio-only device i think you'll get an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by Integration demo of Web, you mean the web demo integration in Dialogflow. Your suggestions are not showing up because they are a Google Assistant feature. The web demo only supports Dialogflow features. The suggestion chips will only work in the [Google Assistant Console](https://console.actions.google.com/) or on a Google Assistant device.

Comment: Ah thanks for clarifying Jordi. Is there an equivalent method for web? Like quick replies in FB?

Comment: No, Dialogflow doesn't have any out of the box equivalent.You can use the custom payload to create custom objects, but these won't work in the web demo. You will need to render it in a custom integration. https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-rich-messages#custom_payload